# What can I do to encrypt data at database level in an MVC3/EF application?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have an MVC3 + EF 4.1 application, against a SQL Server 2008 database, with a requirement that the 'entire table is encrypted' for sensitive data. What are my options for implementing this?

NOTE: I am using the Repository Pattern, with DI swappable concrete repositories, so EF data access is not an absolute requirement here.

Comment: A starting point; http://codingheadache.com/?p=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using Transparent Data Encryption.  This encrypts the entire database and it much easier to use than cell level encryption.

MS SQL does not provide a table based encryption.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx for more detail.

Comment: if some one query directly, let assume SQL injection will that provide security ?? Is TDE provides only physical security ?